# Ninject, select a class based on a loop variable

Tags: c#, ninject

Visual Studio 2010, C#, Ninject version 3.0.0.0.

There is a loop that provides a string variable, X. There is a reference to Ninject in the class. Inside the loop, the variable is used in a kernel.Get method to select the class to  use.

I was under the impression that Ninject would be able to determine the proper class without having to use the Ninject kernel.Get method.  This is just another dependency, which is a situation Ninject is supposed to help avoid.

Is there any way to configure Ninject to determine the proper class to use based on the variable X without using kernel.Get?  I would like to accomplish this without a using Ninject reference in the class.

I have search stackoverflow and the net in general for an answer to this question.  I could have missed something or mis-understood something, but I've already burned a lot of time searching.

Thanks.

OK, there are several classes that use this technique.  Here is one:

The code:

```
foreach (string nodePattern in patternList.GetPattern())
{
    numberOfPatterns++;
    tempReturn = true;
    nodeStack.LoadbatchStructs(nodeStructure);
    patternStack.LoadPattern(nodePattern);
    PatternProperty patternProp = patternStack.PopPattern();
    while (!(patternProp.Identifier == "EndOfStack"))
    {
        matchMode = int.TryParse(patternProp.PatternType, out outIntTestResult)
            ? "#"
            : patternProp.PatternType;
        int.TryParse(patternProp.PatternType, out loopCount);
        classNames.TryGetValue(matchMode, out className);
        IComparePatternAndData patternMatcher = kernel.Get<IComparePatternAndData>(className);
        tempReturn &= patternMatcher.MatchesPattern(nodeStack, patternProp.Identifier, loopCount);
        if (tempReturn == false)
        {
            falseMatches++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            patternProp = patternStack.PopPattern();
            //If there are no more pattern units to match, but there are more node identifiers (e.g. form identifiers or template IDs),
            //then the pattern didn't match.  So set the tempReturn to false.
            if (patternProp.Identifier == "EndOfStack" &&
                !(nodeStack.PeekStructData() == "ENDNODE"))
            {
                tempReturn = false;
            }
        }
    } //Next unit of pattern string
    if (tempReturn == true) numberOfMatches++;
} // Next pattern string

if (numberOfMatches > 0)
{
    tempReturn = true;
}
else
{
    tempReturn = false;
}

return tempReturn;
```

The Ninject bindings.

```
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternCount>().Named("DataMatchesPatternCount");
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternErotem>().Named("DataMatchesPatternErotem");
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternStar>().Named("DataMatchesPatternStar");
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternPlus>().Named("DataMatchesPatternPlus");
```

The class constructor:

```
public class ValidateNodeStructure : IValidateNodeStructure
{
    private readonly INodeStructure nodeStruct;
    private readonly BatchStructStack nodeStack;
    private  INodePattern patternList;
    private readonly IPatternStack patternStack;
    private readonly IGetClassNameFromPatternType getClassNames;

    public ValidateNodeStructure(INodeStructure nodeStructure, BatchStructStack nodeStack,  IPatternStack patternStack, IGetClassNameFromPatternType getClassNames)
    {
        this.nodeStruct = nodeStructure;
        this.nodeStack = nodeStack;
        this.patternStack = patternStack;
        this.getClassNames = getClassNames;
    }
```

Comment: You've made multiple pattern errors.  First of all, you're using a Service Locator anti-pattern.  Secondly, you should be coding to an interface, not an implementation, otherwise your dependency injection is worthless.  Finally, you should inject any required dependencies into your class so that the loop can consume it.  It's also worth noting that dealing with these abstract questions does not make a very good question.  It would be best if you could provide your code.

Comment: How about showing us what you have ?

Comment: I summarized the code because there is a lot of it.  I will see what I can do to provide examples.  I am using interfaces, that's how I wire  up Ninject.  I very well could be doing it wrong, however, which is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ninject like a dictionary but you've already got a dictionary in your code: `classNames`.

Instead of adding `Named` to your bindings for `IComparePatternAndData`, why don't you add the "name" data to the `IComparePatternAndData` interface (as a property) and inject all `IComparePatternAndData` into `IGetClassNameFromPatternType` -- (of course you should change the name then b/c it serves different functionality. I've renamed it to `IPatternDictionary`).

```
public interface IComparePatternAndData
{
    int PatternId { get; }

    // of course the actual compare method(s) go here as well...
}

public interface IPatternDictionary
{
    bool TryGetValue(int key, out IComparePatternAndData value);
}

public class PatternDictionary : Dictionary<int, IComparePatternAndData>, IPatternDictionary
{
    public PatternDictionary(IComparePatternAndData[] patterns)
    {
        foreach (IComparePatternAndData pattern in patterns)
        {
            this[pattern.PatternId] = pattern;
        }
    }
}
```

bindings:

```
Bind<IPatternDictionary>().To<PatternDictionary>();
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternCount>();
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternErotem>();
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternStar>();
Bind<IComparePatternAndData>().To<DataMatchesPatternPlus>();
```

Usage:

```
IComparePatternAndData patternMatcher;
patternDictionary.TryGetValue(matchMode, out patternMatcher);
```

instead of:

```
   classNames.TryGetValue(matchMode, out className);
   IComparePatternAndData patternMatcher = kernel.Get<IComparePatternAndData>(className);
```

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit.  This is the first project I've used C#, first for object oriented programming, and first for Ninject.  Your solution is awesome.  I used it in the code posted, just changed the int identifier to a string for ?,*,+, and #.  As far as I'm concerned you are a NINJECT GOD!!  Thanks.

Comment: @darkcandle well thank you for the praise although i'm sure there's quite a handful of people who know ninject better than me. On another note, it would be nice if you could [accept the answer and/or upvote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question on SE.  I apparently don't have enough of something to upvote your solution.  But I did accept the answer. Thanks again.